Should I store CSRF token in my client Java app?
I have a REST API Spring Boot application (called app "A"). It calls another API (called "B").
"B" is OAuth2 secured and requires CSRF token for POST/PUT/DELETE.
Every "A" -> "B" call contains a JWT OAuth2 token from Azure. CSRF token can be obtained by "A" by calling a getCsrfToken() "B"'s endpoint. 
The question is: should "A" call for a CSRF token for every unsafe operation or should it be stored in a Java service and reused until it expires?

I think it is about balance between safety and usability. Obviously, it is more safe to get a new token every time. But it can lead to problems with usability.
There are several approaches for working with tokens:

Synchronizer Token
Encryption based Token Pattern
HMAC Based Token

In case of using Synchronizer Token Pattern, you should send it with every request. It is not recommended to use GET request for it also. It should be generated once per session or once per request. But it can lead to a situation, when the user goes to previous page, which contains a token that is no longer valid. Then it will be a  false positive security event.
Encryption based Token Pattern doesn't require storing on server side. It is using encryption. That is a stateless method.
HMAC Based Token doesn't require storing it on client side. It is using HMAC (hash-based message authentication code) for encryption.
You should answer yourself also, if your application is stateful, or otherwise, stateless, and pick the right method. Also, check the OWASP Cross-Site Request Forgery Prevention Cheat Sheet.
